# can anyone explain how Sencha Touch controllers couple with relevant views

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I always wonder

1. How Sencha Touch 2 knows which controller to run first and which one is the next
2. How does ST2 knows which controller is in charge of which view.
3. Can we have more than one controller on one view, if yes, how to wire them up?
4. Can we have more than one views controlled by one controller? if yes, how does the events flow?
5. How to wire up view1 with controller1,......, viewX with controllerX.

Thank you.

Comment: why vote for close? I'm happy to learn.

Comment: I am following this question. Meanwhile, could you tell me how do you know if someone voted for close?

Comment: hi @SunnyRGupta thank you. If you take a look at the share | edit | close (1) | delete | flag, you will find the number after close which means the number of people who voted for closing the question. And it's always a good practice to give reasons of closing.

Comment: Wow, although I cannot see any close link, all I see is share | edit | flag

Comment: Hi @SunnyRGupta I guess only author of questions can see that. Now it's number 2. I wonder why there people are not willing to explain.

Comment: I guess they are downvoting because your question is wide, it's made of at least 5 sub questions, where the SO would impose to be as specific as possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. I think it's a useful question anyway, I'm trying to answer point by point ;)

Comment: hi @Anubis thank you for your explanation. I agree that 1 post 1 question, but sometimes I think the policy needs to be changed to allow people ask a group of associated questions in one post which makes more sense and is convenient for both askers and readers. Also, looking forward to your answers :) thx

Comment: @Franva Are you satisfied with the answers? Would you mind accepting one of the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer refers to Sencha Touch 2.3.1.

There is no real "coupling", except the relations you define through `refs` and `control` property of the controllers http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller.

> All of the Controllers that an Application uses are specified in the Application's Ext.app.Application.controllers config. The Application automatically instantiates each Controller and keeps references to each

1. I guess the order in which the controllers are included is defined by the `controllers` property of app.js (it would be pretty easy to verify anyway by putting some console.log() in the init method of each controller).
2. There is no such a relation of "being in charge" for a View, controllers have references to Views, that is all. It's worth mentioning that controllers may require `views` (and `stores` and `models`) but that is just related to inclusion in the packaging phase, there are no "bindings" to those components at runtime.
3. It's possible, just define two controllers that have both a reference to the same view. That would be bad anyway, because it would spread the logic for the same view in multiple places.
4. Yes it's possible. For example I use to write a single controller to manage set of simple views always used together (for example a wizard). You simply have all the handlers for the events of those views in a single controller.
5. The encouraged way is through through `refs` and `control` property of the controller http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller.

In summary, in my opinion, controllers are more a *tool for the developer* to *organize* code meaningfully and to improve maintainability, rather than a rigid implementation of MVC in the framework.

Comment: Thank you Anubis. I also got a question, could you please take a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058929/how-to-do-a-self-destroy-inside-a-custom-component-in-sencha-touch

Answer (score 3):

- Re.: 1 - Controllers are initialized, if you mean that by "run", in the order they are listed in application `controllers:[]` array. See also [ext application startup sequence](http://extjs.eu/ext-application-startup-sequence/):
- Re.: 2 - Controllers just listen to events that come from views. The listeners are installed in `init` method of controller
- Re.: 3 technically yes - more than one controller can listen to events of same view - but it is not a good practice. It's like to have more bosses
- Re.: 4 yes and it is ver common that one controllers controls more than one view
- Re.: 5 see [application architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture)