# How to do a self-destroy inside a custom component in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

update:

new code:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.MyCmp',{
     extend:'Ext.Component'
    ,alias:'widget.mycmp'
    ,config:{
         html:'MyCmp'
    }
    ,initialize:function() {
        var me = this;
        console.log(me);
        Ext.Function.defer(me.destroy, 5000, me);

        Ext.Function.defer(function(){
            console.log('after 8 seconds');
            console.log(this);

        }, 8000, me);
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    ref:{
        cmp: 'mycmp'

    },

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype:'mycmp'            
        });


    }
});
```

Still after 8 seconds, I still can print out the component.  Here is the console log:

> Class {onInitializedListeners: Array[0], initialConfig: Object, id:
>   "ext-mycmp-1", getUniqueId: function, getId: function…}  VM1639:39
>
> after 8 seconds VM1639:43 Class {onInitializedListeners: Array[0],
>   initialConfig: Object, id: "ext-mycmp-1", getUniqueId: function,
>   getId: function…}

---

I am trying to add a self-destroy function in a custom component.
But it simply doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('NoiseComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'noisestation',
    config: {
        name: null,
        updatedTime: new Date(),
        listeners: {
            destroy: function() {

                console.log("do something before destroy()");
                //thisComponent.destroy();
            },
            updatedata: function(thisComponent, newData, eOpts) {
                var startTime = newData[0].get("NoiseTime");
                this.config.updatedTime = new Date();

            },
            initialize: function(thisComponent, eOpts) {
                console.log("initialize component");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    thisComponent.selfDestory(thisComponent);

                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    },

    drawNoise: function() {

        console.log("drawNoise");
    },
    selfDestory: function(thisComponent) {
        console.log("self-destroy");
        thisComponent.destroy(thisComponent);
    }
});

var c = Ext.create("NoiseComponent");

console.log(c);

c.destroy();
//c.fireEvent('destroy');

console.log("after destroyed");
console.log(c);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("after 5s");
    console.log(c);
}, 5000);
```

Here is the console log I got:

> initialize component VM1591:44 Class {onInitializedListeners:
>   Array[0], initialConfig: Object, id: "ext-noisestation-1",
>   getUniqueId: function, getId: function…}  VM1591:72 do something
>   before destroy() VM1591:65 after destroyed VM1591:77 Class
>   {onInitializedListeners: Array[0], initialConfig: Object, id:
>   "ext-noisestation-1", getUniqueId: function, getId: function…} 
>   VM1591:78 self-destroy VM1591:60 do something before destroy()
>   VM1591:65 after 5s VM1591:81 Class {onInitializedListeners: Array[0],
>   initialConfig: Object, id: "ext-noisestation-1", getUniqueId:
>   function, getId: function…}  VM1591:82

Here is my sencha jsfiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6cl

Comment: That's syntax error in your app.js

Comment: sorry, updated and still the component cannot do self-destroy. please take a look at the sencha fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to destroy the component 5s after it is initialized. If so, the following code does it:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.MyCmp',{
     extend:'Ext.Component'
    ,alias:'widget.mycmp'
    ,config:{
         html:'MyCmp'
    }
    ,destroy:function() {
        console.log('destroy override');
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
    ,initialize:function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.Function.defer(function(){
            console.log('Destroying after delay')
            me.destroy();
        }, 5000, me);
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    ref:{
        cmp: 'mycmp'

    },

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype:'mycmp'            
        });        
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, I want to destroy the component when certain conditions are meet and also I want to override the destroy() method. How do I do it? Also, how can I check whether the component is destroyed or not? thank  you :)

Comment: Hi Saki, I tried, but the component is still there. please see my updated post and fiddler. thanks

Comment: See the updated Fiddle code in the answer. It works fine for me.

Comment: I probably see your point - there is still something in `c` variable after destroy. It is the reference to the destroyed component, you can just set it to `null` to cleanup completely.

Comment: Hi Saki, Thank you for your reply. When to put event listener in to the listeners section under config property and when to put the event listener directly under the component itself? From what I've seen, it seems interchangeable?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24053768/692525) Note: Even if it might work if listeners are not in config in `Ext.define`, I'd rather put them there for consistency.

Comment: then why did you put the destroy() method directly under the custom component?? this is where it makes me confused.

Comment: That is not a listener, it's destroy override.

Comment: Oh~~, so all events go under the listeners section in config property, but all component built-in methods go directly under component itself, right? Also I ttried to set it to null --> this = null inside the destroy() method, but an error says Invalid left-hand side in assignment. so there is no way to set the component self to null inside the component as we cannot find any other reference of itself inside itself.